# error adding image object

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, image

The following code produces error:

```
ImageIcon i=new ImageIcon("logo.png");
Image scaleImage=i.getImage().getScaledInstance(10,10,Image.SCALE_DEFAULT);
mainPanel.add(scaleImage);
```

The error is `cannot find method add(Image)`.
Why it is giving  this error?
[image]

Comment: Is this a compile tijme or runtime error?

Comment: Please learn how to copy/paste from the command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it like that. `JPanel` does not accept `Image` as parameter (that's what the error tells you).

You have two options:

- draw the image in the panel instead. The solution uses the `paintComponent(..)` method.
- use a `JLabel` and an `ImageIcon`

The answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299495/java-swing-how-to-add-an-image-to-a-jpanel) will show you how to do it either way.

Answer (score 0):

```
ImageIcon i=new ImageIcon("logo.png");
Image scaleImage=i.getImage().getScaledInstance(70,70,Image.SCALE_DEFAULT);
ImageIcon ii=new ImageIcon(scaleImage);
JLabel pic=new JLabel(ii);
mainP.add(pic);  // now you can add
```