# Adding an image to a JPanel background

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, image-resizing

How can I add an image to a JPanel background. The image will not be scaled or resized. Thanks.

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/299495/java-swing-how-to-add-an-image-to-a-jpanel

Comment: and JPanel can be resized or not ..., for GUI related question your tag would be Swing + JPanel + Icon/Image/ImageIcon, look like as again empty question without reading tutorial, please post here code that shows your issue with Image/ImageIcon placed into JPanel that shouldn't be resiziable

Comment: @Preston Thanks. The example in the link answered the question.

Answer (score 2):

```
/**
 * @author
 *
 */
public class ImagePanel extends JPanel {

    private Image image = null;

    public ImagePanel(String filename) {
        this.image = new ImageIcon(filename).getImage();
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.getWidth(null), image.getHeight(null), null);
    }

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ImagePanel panel = new ImagePanel("resources/image.jpg");

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Frame");
        frame.setSize(800, 600);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Won't this scale with resize? See also [Initial Threads](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).

Comment: Perfect, if only more people would be this short with there answers!

Answer (score -1):

You can override one of these methods:

```
JComponent.paint(Graphics g)
JComponent.paintComponent(Graphics g)
```

Comment: please remove `JComponent.paint(Graphics g)`, that really wrong method for painting in Java6' Swing