# swing: about resizing JFrames and conditional scrolling

Tags: java, swing, scroll, jframe

I have a `JFrame` with a single `JPanel` inside. The panel displays images that are received from the network at runtime. These images are usually big, but can have any size. Considering this and given that I might add a menu bar to the frame in the future, I'd like to do the following:

- For each received image, the panel resizes to its exact size.
- If the image (and hence the resized panel) exceeds a certain maximum value in width or height (e.g.: the screen size - 100px), then the frame should resize to the maximum allowed value and enable scrollbars.
- Otherwise, the frame should adjust its size to display the entire panel without any padding. So the frame size is the content panel size plus the borders and the title bar (and the menu bar if I finally add it).

Is there a way to do this? If not, what would be the best alternative?

Thanks in advance

EDIT:

The problem, to summarize, is *how to resize the parent frame to adjust to its child content panel*. This is the opposite of what most people do (resize panel to fit frame).

For point #3, I already have the content panel dimension, so the problem is reduced to calc the size of the frame's frame (top title bar height, borders width). With that, I could resize the frame to a size such as the content pane fits exactly inside.

Comment: sounds pretty standard behaviour, what's wrong with pack()?

Comment: @kleopatra dunno the reason, but doesn't work. Launch the frame with minimum size, then when the images are received, I resize the panel. At that point, if I call pack, the frame doesn't change its size.

Comment: it's not _your_ job to resize anything, it's the LayoutManager's job: let the panel decide its prefSize based on the image size, let it revalidate itself on receiving a new image, then call pack on the frame - worksformealways (from the top of my head, don't have a IDE handy)

Comment: @kleopatra There's only a frame with a custom pane (where I have overridden `paintComponent`) inside. Calling `pack` doesn't work. I tried calling also validate on itself and on the contentPane, without success. I tried also commenting the `frame.setMinimumSize` line, no luck. The custom pane is called `setSize` after every update.

Comment: the way you are describing is the wrong thingy to do - read my last comment and implement that in an sscce. Then we'll see if/how/what isn't working :-)

Comment: @kleopatra Ok, I did a major modification and went to the recommended way of using an ImageIcon and a Label. Now `pack` works, but the icon doesn't refresh after calling setImage. I called validate and invalidate on panels but no luck here. I also have an additional problem and it is that for pack to work I had to remove my ScrollPane and add the things directly to the frame, so now when the icon is larger than the frame max size, theres no scroll.

Comment: -1 for still not showing an sscce. Descriptions of your trials (which sound unusual) are not useful.

Comment: @kleopatra Thanks, I've no time for that. The ImageIcon approach is not suitable for my needs. I've seen a number of answers in other questions recommending my initial panel approach, as it is more efficient for high frequency updates. The problem of using panel with only `paintComponent` overriden is that it doesn't provide size info to its parent container, so calling `pack` simply and plain doesn't work.

Comment: _I've no time for that_  shaking head in disbelieve ;-) Seems like you also didn't have time to read my comments carefully (one last hint: you are erring on _**only** paintComponent overriden_)

Comment: I know XD. I took the idea from here http://stackoverflow.com/a/299555/813951 but seems that I should also override other methods to get the thing working. I'll take on that soon. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2):

- put images as Icon to the JLabel instead of drawing image to JPanel
- you can schrink image pixels size before diplaying in the GUI by using
  [Image#getScaledInstance(int width, int height, int hints)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Image.html#getScaledInstance%28int,%20int,%20int%29)
- notice you have to close `InputStream` corectly in the finally block, otherwise these `Objects` stays in the memory until [OutOfMemoryError](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/OutOfMemoryError.html) locking current JVM instance

EDIT

```
put images as Icon to the JLabel
```

but

```
pictures = new ImageIcon("Xxxxx");
pictures.getImage().flush();
myLabel.setIcon(pictures);
```

- this code should be better to call from `SwingWorker`, or from `Runnable#Thread`, but in this case you have to wrap the code line `myLabel.setIcon(pictures);` into `invokeLater()`,
- more about `SwingWorker` and `invokeLater()` in the tutorial Concurency in Swing, bunch of answers about concurency on this forum

Comment: Thanks for your advice, but I don't want to resize the images. These should be displayed in full size. What I need is to enable scrolling or not depending on the image size and the total display size.

Comment: It is interesting how Swing is not so well designed as to allow this easily, and instead a lot of people choose to use the image icon hack.