# display screenshots and split them into two realtime

Tags: java, screenshot, awtrobot

I am new at Java.

I am trying to display the screenshot of the present screen and update it realtime.
It is working fine if i am displaying it just once
But for my college project I am supposed to display the same screenshot on two adjacent screens.

I am not able to figure out how to implement this.

I found two codes and was trying to implement them together so that I get the required outcome.
http://www.ivoronline.com/Coding/Languages/JAVA/Tutorials/JAVA%20-%20File%20-%20Image%20-%20Display%20Multiple%20Images.php

[Capturing and displaying an image using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12064331/capturing-and-displaying-an-image-using-java)

This is what my present code is.

```
     import javax.swing.*;

     import java.awt.Rectangle;
     import java.awt.Robot;
     import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

     public class OrionCode_v02 {

     public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
     Robot robot = new Robot();

    //JPanel panel = new JPanel();

    JFrame theGUI = new JFrame();
    //theGUI.getContentPane().add (panel);
    theGUI.setTitle("TestApp");
    theGUI.setSize(640, 720);        
    theGUI.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    theGUI.setVisible(true);

    JLabel picLabel = new JLabel();
    JLabel picLabel2 = new JLabel();
    theGUI.add(picLabel);
    theGUI.add(picLabel2);

    while (true) 
    {
        BufferedImage screenShot = robot.createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(0,0,320,720)); // x-coord, y-coord, width, height
        BufferedImage screenShot1 = robot.createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(320,0,320,720)); // x-coord, y-coord, width, height

        picLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(screenShot1)); 
        picLabel2.setIcon(new ImageIcon(screenShot));

        theGUI.add(picLabel);
        theGUI.add(picLabel2);


      /*  
        panel.add (new JLabel (new ImageIcon (screenShot)));
        panel.add (new JLabel (new ImageIcon (screenShot1)));
    */
    }
}
```

}

It doesn't display screenshot1.
only displays the screenshot.
If I swap the two commands of picLabel.setIcon, then it displays screenshot1.

I need to display both the screenshots together.
How do I go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JFrame has [BorderLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/BorderLayout.html) by default, which makes `add(Component)` method to add component always to center part of frame by default, replacing any components already put there. So you only have `picLabel2` in frame. You can add components to specific parts by using overloaded `add`:

```
theGUI.add(picLabel, BorderLayout.WEST);
theGUI.add(picLabel2, BorderLayout.EAST);
```

You also have unnecessary `add()` calls inside your loop.