# Java screenshot (using Robot and BufferedImage.getRGB)

Tags: java, pixel, bufferedimage, awtrobot

I discovered the Robot class yesterday, and thought it was pretty cool. Today I wanted to experiment with it and see what was possible; so I decided I wanted to make a program that took a screenshot of the entire screen, and rendered out an image pixel by pixel on a JPanel. I have the program finished (two classes), but it isn't working and I can't find out why (I HAVE looked over the code a few times). Here's the code:

(FIRST CLASS)

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class One { 
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        BufferedImage screenCap = null;
        Rectangle screenRect = new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
        try {
            screenCap = new Robot().createScreenCapture(screenRect);
            Two imageRenderer = new Two(screenCap, screenRect);
            imageRenderer.doRender();
            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            frame.setVisible(true);
            frame.setResizable(false);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
            frame.add(imageRenderer);
            frame.pack();
        } catch (AWTException e) { 
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

(SECOND CLASS)

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Two extends JPanel {
    private BufferedImage screenCap;
    private Rectangle screenRect;

    private Color pixelRGB;
    //c1 and c2 are the x and y co-ordinates of the selected pixel.
    private int c1, c2;

    public Two(BufferedImage sC, Rectangle rect) {
        screenCap = sC;
        screenRect = rect;
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(rect.width, rect.height));
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        g.setColor(pixelRGB);
        g.drawRect(c1, c2, 1, 1);
    }

    public void doRender() {
        for(int i=0; i<screenRect.width; i++) {
            for(int j=0; j<screenRect.height; j++) {
                pixelRGB = new Color(screenCap.getRGB(i, j));
                c1 = i;
                c2 = j;
                repaint();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have googled around this problem to no avail.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `Two` should probably be an instance of a `JLabel` that is displaying `screenCap`.

Answer (score 3):

In order to make it work, just replace your `paintComponent()` method in your class `Two` with the following:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    g.drawImage(screenCap, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), null);
}
```

You can also get rid of the `doRender()` method.

Comment: Oh, thanks! I didn't know about drawImage() (Still getting to know the API)

Answer (score 1):

`Two` should probably be an instance of a `JLabel` that is displaying `screenCap`.  E.G.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Screenshot {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Rectangle screenRect = new Rectangle(
                Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());

        final BufferedImage screenCap = 
                new Robot().createScreenCapture(screenRect);
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new ImageIcon(screenCap));
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```

Drop it in a scroll pane if you wish to be really neat about it.  Batteries not included.

In case it is not obvious:  A `JOptionPane` uses a `JLabel` to render an `ImageIcon`.

Answer (score 0):

Each time you repaint, you paint white over the whole panel, then do only a single pixel. So after each one, you'll only get one pixel. It also shouldn't be necessary to call `repaint` many times. In fact, when you call `repaint`, it does not immediately actually call `paintComponent`. It simply submits a request to repaint, which swing will eventually do. And it might not be one-to-one. E.g., many calls to `repaint` might result in only one call to `paintComponent`. You should try to write code so that a single call to `paintComponent` will completely display the component.

To do this, you can use `g.drawImage` to display a BufferedImage. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299495/java-swing-how-to-add-an-image-to-a-jpanel) post for more information on displaying an image in a JPanel.