# Take screenshot of internal div with scrolling with Watir webdriver

Tags: selenium, watir

I already save my screenshots of the entire page using this command successfully:

```
@browser.screenshot.save "html-report/#{screenshot_name}"
```

However, the screen has changed and now it contains an internal div with scrolling, containing the crucial information that I want to capture.

Instead of using the command above to capture the whole page, is there a way to capture just the all contents of this scrolling div?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you really need a screenshot of div's contents? What about just taking the text or html of the div?

Comment: That's actually a good idea. However this DIV is actually a sale receipt so it would be interesting to have the "real" thing screenshotted.

In any case I will talk to the business people and see if that's enough. Thanks for the idea!

Comment: @JustinKo can you put in answer what you suggestin?

Comment: @paul, the suggestion would not really answer the question. If you are looking for a code example, it would have just been `@browser.div.text` or `@browser.div.html`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to capture the screenshot of only a specific element using Selenium Webdriver?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13832322/how-to-capture-the-screenshot-of-only-a-specific-element-using-selenium-webdrive)

Answer (score 3):

Already implemented as watir plugin https://github.com/ansoni/watir-extensions-element-screenshot

Comment: worked perfect for me.  this should probably be marked as the correct answer