# Get background color from src in selenium WebDriver

Tags: html, css, selenium

The x-path is like <  img id="" src="/A/A/B.png" style="">

I am required to find the color of the image , the style does not contain anything about color. It contains information only about height,width.

I am sure in the src path the fill attribute would be present.But how am I suppose to get till that?

Here is what i think of doing:

```
String css = driver.findElement(By.Xpath("..blah../img").getCSSValue("background-color");
```

but i get 'transparent' as answer .How do i get over it?

Comment: As per your question, i think you are trying to retrieve the background color of image, if so,  there is no way of you retrieving the background color of image(if there is no background color), the return type would transparent, if i didn't get your question correctly, please be more specific

Comment: There is an image, but it is partly transparent, partly green in color....but the x-path given above will highlight both transparent as well as the green part.I tried to find more precise xpath but in vain.So i am trying to find out some more specific way of getting the color of img present only

Answer (score 2):

This will definetely works:

driver.findElement(By.xpath("..blah../img")).getCssValue("background-color").toString();

The problem is either your image is really transparent or color is defined in its **parent**.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!, Could you please elaborate about the parent part. Is it like the parent is the src??

Comment: No, I meant that background could be made not within this <img> tag, but using some of the parent elements, which is defining the background color for all the sub elements.

Comment: The parent elements have no attributes related to the color of img, this image is completely from a different source(I can say for sure)....

Comment: Then are you sure that the background is not transparent? Is it possible to see what are you checking? Can you also see the css attributes in Chrome dev tools?

Comment: I was told to be confidential about the information..:( . I have been using Firepath to check the attributes and stuff..,searched in style attribute, but no where i can see the color....

Comment: Then, it's the thing, there is no background color, and it's transparent (translucent)

Comment: I think that would be fine.

Comment: Do you mean the color of the picture by itself? Is it multi-color or just one?

Comment: So, you should make a screenshot of specific element (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13832322/how-to-capture-the-screenshot-of-only-a-specific-element-using-selenium-webdrive) and then check the color with something like http://pastebin.com/uXfz3GE0 (I'm checking the first pixel here)

Comment: Does help.. I will check and let you know.! Thanks!