# How to take screenshot of element using python3 and selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I want to take screenshot of the element.
I tried with below mentioned code:

```
ElementIs=driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//body/img")
ElementIs.screenshot('abc.jpg')
```

but got error:

```
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.47.1-y3.4.egg\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 448, in _execute   return self._parent.execute(command, params)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.47.1-y3.4.egg\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 196, in execute self.error_handler.check_response(response)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.47.1-py3.4.egg\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 102, in check_responsevalue = json.loads(value_json)
File "C:\Python34\lib\json\__init__.py", line 318, in loads   return _default_decoder.decode(s)
File "C:\Python34\lib\json\decoder.py", line 343, in decode   obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
File "C:\Python34\lib\json\decoder.py", line 361, in raw_decode raise ValueError(errmsg("Expecting value", s, err.value)) from None ValueError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of problems:

1. `find_elements_by_xpath` returns a list, and you can't request a screenshot on a list. Did you mean `find_element_by_xpath`?
2. In any case, with the exception of Microsoft Edge, [no WebDriver actually implements element-based screenshots](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/912). You have to generate a full-window screenshot and crop it.

See [my earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35418122/954442) on this topic for more background and workarounds.

Answer (score 1):

With Firefox you can:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
qr = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.css_class')
qr.screenshot("abc.jpg")
```

You can use class, id or tags in find_element_by_css_selector.