# selenium python element.screenshot() not working

Tags: python, selenium, screenshot, chrome-web-driver

```
 from selenium import webdriver

 browser = webdriver.Chrome()
 browser.get("http://www.baidu.com")
 browser.find_element_by_id('su').screenshot('E:/test.png')
 browser.quit()
```

when I run above code, I got the errors,my python version is 2.7.13, selenium is 3.1

[code error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/903HU.png)

> [0315/220804.111:ERROR:angle_platform_impl.cc(33)] ANGLE
>   Display::initialize err or 5: DXGI 1.2 required to present to HWNDs
>   owned by another process.
>   [0315/220804.111:ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(646)] eglInitialize D3D11
>   failed with e rror EGL_NOT_INITIALIZED, trying next display type
>   Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\test.py", line 5, in 
>       browser.find_element_by_id('su').screenshot('E:/test.png')   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py",
>   line 443, in screenshot
>       png = self.screenshot_as_png   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py",
>   line 430, in screenshot_as_png
>       return base64.b64decode(self.screenshot_as_base64.encode('ascii'))   File
>   "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py",
>   line 420, in screenshot_as_base64
>       return self._execute(Command.ELEMENT_SCREENSHOT)['value']   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py",
>   line 491, in _execute
>       return self._parent.execute(command, params)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",
>   l ine 238, in execute
>       self.error_handler.check_response(response)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py"
>   , line 164, in check_response
>       raise exception_class(value) selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown
>   command: session
>   /4a58c13f918aa319b2df6ef70ac2ca51/element/0.4724184220629968-1/screenshot

Comment: This method as I know currently works with `Edge` only

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't look like you can screenshot a particular element with selenium alone. See here, for example: [How to take screenshot of element using python3 and selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36011138/how-to-take-screenshot-of-element-using-python3-and-selenium][1]).

There are workarounds such as this: [How to take partial screenshot with Selenium WebDriver in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15018372/how-to-take-partial-screenshot-with-selenium-webdriver-in-python][1]).

You can also take a screenshot of the page and crop it. In that case, these work:

```
browser.get_screenshot_as_file('/example/file/path.png')
```

or

```
browser.save_screenshot('/example/file/path.png')
```

Comment: What about http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.screenshot ?

Comment: Has that worked for you? I've tried element.screenshot(file) a few times and it has never worked. That's what the original poster was trying also.

Comment: It seems that it has not been implemented yet. Take a look at [this](https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium/issues/912).