# How do I take a screenshot of DOM element using intern js?

Tags: css, selenium, screenshot, intern, regression-testing

I'm using [intern.js](https://theintern.github.io/) to test a web app. I can execute tests and create screenshots when they fail. I want to create a screenshot for specific element in order to do some CSS regression testing using tools like [resemble.js](https://huddle.github.io/Resemble.js/). Is it possible? How can I do? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
driver.get("http://www.google.com");
WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.id("hplogo"));   

//Get entire page screenshot
File screenshot = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
BufferedImage  fullImg = ImageIO.read(screenshot);

//Get the location of element on the page
Point point = ele.getLocation();

//Get width and height of the element
int eleWidth = ele.getSize().getWidth();
int eleHeight = ele.getSize().getHeight();

//Crop the entire page screenshot to get only element screenshot
BufferedImage eleScreenshot= fullImg.getSubimage(point.getX(), point.getY(), eleWidth,
    eleHeight);
ImageIO.write(eleScreenshot, "png", screenshot);

//Copy the element screenshot to disk
File screenshotLocation = new File("C:\\images\\GoogleLogo_screenshot.png");
FileUtils.copyFile(screen, screenshotLocation);
```

Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13832322/how-to-capture-the-screenshot-of-a-specific-element-rather-than-entire-page-usin).

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a built in way to do this with Intern. The `takeScreenshot` method simply calls Selenium's screenshot service, which returns a screenshot of the entire page as a base-64 encoded PNG. Intern's `takeScreenshot` converts this to a Node buffer before handing the result to the user.

To crop the image you will need to use an external library or tool such as [png-crop](https://github.com/chenglou/png-crop) (note that I've never used this). The code might look like the following (untested):

```
var image;
var size;
var position;

return this.remote
    // ...
    .takeScreenshot()
    .then(function (imageBuffer) {
        image = imageBuffer;
    })
    .findById('element')
    .getSize()
    .then(function (elementSize) {
        size = elementSize;
    })
    .getPosition()
    .then(function (elementPosition) {
        position = elementPosition;
    })
    .then(function () {
        // assuming you've loaded png-crop as PNGCrop
        var config = {
            width: size.width,
            height: size.height,
            top: position.y,
            left: position.x
        };
        // need to return a Promise since PNGCrop.crop is an async method
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            PNGCrop.crop(image, 'cropped.png', config, function (err) {
                if (err) {
                    reject(err);
                }
                else {
                    resolve();
                }
            });
        });
    })
```

Comment: thank you, I'll use something like WebdriverCSS that is able to do what i need.

Comment: Interesting, I hadn't seen WebDriverCSS. We're actually working on a visual regression testing update for Intern, so this type of operation may become a bit easier in the future.

Comment: How to import node.js module (PNGCrop) in Intern test module?

Comment: Assuming you're writing your test modules in AMD format, and assuming that you've installed png-crop, use a dependency of `intern/dojo/node!png-crop` in your test suite.