# Groovy script too long for string

Tags: javascript, groovy, spock, html2canvas, geb

I would like to execute a script from a JavaScript file but due the same origin policy measure, I can't.

I tried to execute put the script in a string and pass it to the function.

```
js.exec()
```

However I cannot execute this script due the fact that the string is too long.

This is how I pass the script.

```
class TheClass extend GebReportingSpec {
....
and:'I execute the script'
      js.exec('''
        $.getScript("http://localhost/jscript/html2canvas.js", function() { 
        var height = Math.round($("#TopImageContainer").height());
        var width =  Math.round($("#TopImageContainer").height());
        // function() { 
        html2canvas($("#TopImageContainer"), {
            onrendered: function (canvas) {
                 var tempcanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
                 tempcanvas.width = width;
                 tempcanvas.height = height;
                 var context = tempcanvas.getContext("2d");
                context.drawImage(canvas,0,0,width,height,0,0,width,height);
                 var link = document.createElement("a");
                 link.href = tempcanvas.toDataURL("image/png"); 
                 link.download = "myElement.png";
               link.click();
          }
    }); 

     });''')
    }
```

I am getting the following error:

> The given string is 126694 Unicode code units long, but only a maximum of 65535 is allowed.

What can I do?

Comment: Maybe you should just copy the functions you need.

Comment: I tried it but the string is still too long

Comment: How is this related to `groovy`/`spock`/`geb`?

Comment: can you reduce your problem to a [mcve]?

Comment: Are you trying to create a screenshot or what is it that you actually want to do here?

Comment: @LeonardBrünings I am trying to creat a screenshot of an element, not the whole page.

Comment: I'd suggest to just use Webdriver instead https://stackoverflow.com/a/13834607/2145769

Comment: Strange. That string you are using is not nearly 65535 chars long. Can you provide a full stack trace?