# How to screenshot specific ID on IE website with VBA and Selenium

Tags: vba, excel, selenium, screenshot

I'm trying to screenshot a specific ID which contains a table of weather forecasts for the week (https://forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php?lat=41.8843&lon=-87.6324#.W5kg1ehKiUk, and the ID is "seven-day-forecast-body")
but my code doesn't seem to work, and I've found few VBA-specific examples. Here's what I'm working with. Much appreciated, thank you.

```
Sub seleniumtutorial()

Dim bot As New WebDriver

bot.Start "IE", "https://forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php?lat=41.8843&lon=-87.6324#.W5kg1ehKiUk"

bot.Get "/"

bot.FindElementById("seven-day-forecast-body").SaveAs (ActiveWorkbook.Path + "/chicago.jpg")

bot.Quit

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Syntax is

```
bot.TakeScreenshot.SaveAs ActiveWorkbook.Path + "/chicago.jpg"
```

If you need to size to get only that part of the screen then you need to crop the screenshot image. Please see the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13832322/how-to-capture-the-screenshot-of-a-specific-element-rather-than-entire-page-usin) and VBA examples in search from [here](https://www.google.co.uk/search?safe=strict&ei=ZDOZW8j_DuXSgAa68KrYAw&q=vba%20crop%20a%20screenshot&oq=vba%20crop%20a%20screenshot&gs_l=psy-ab.3...2528.2997.0.3134.4.4.0.0.0.0.188.429.0j3.3.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..1.1.186...0i13k1j0i13i30k1j0i13i5i30k1.0.MveC4-PWju4) for pointers.

You can use Scroll functionality of selenium to centre your image on a particular element.

---

Scrolling element to centre:

```
Option Explicit
Sub seleniumtutorial()

    Dim bot As New WebDriver

    bot.Start "IE", "https://forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php?lat=41.8843&lon=-87.6324#.W5kg1ehKiUk"

    bot.get "/"

    Dim element As Object
    Set element = bot.FindElementById("seven-day-forecast-body")

    Dim scrollElementIntoMiddle As String
    scrollElementIntoMiddle = "var viewPortHeight = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientHeight, window.innerHeight || 0);" _
                            + "var elementTop = arguments[0].getBoundingClientRect().top;" _
                            + "window.scrollBy(0, elementTop-(viewPortHeight/2));"

    bot.ExecuteScript scrollElementIntoMiddle, element

    bot.TakeScreenshot.SaveAs ActiveWorkbook.Path + "/chicago.jpg"

    bot.Quit

End Sub
```

---

Alternative is:

```
bot.ExecuteScript "arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element
```

Comment: Any follow-up on this?