# Implement an “add to basket” button classifier

Tags: python, html, json, deep-learning, classification

I have a problem that I confused about attacking it. 
This is the task:

We would like you to implement an “add to basket” button classifier on the dataset provided. Specifically, we want the classifier to identify the id attribute of the correct “add to basket” button.

It has been provided to me a dataset of 1000 website
Each website has two files: 
1)HTML files - each one being the DOM representation of an e-commerce product page
2)JSON files - metadata for each HTML file. The ‘button_id’ key indicates, via the HTML tag attribute “id”, where the correct “add to basket” button is on each associated HTML file.

I don't the HTLM file with the product page provided any help in this task. 
It is a standard product page with a lot of other information that is not relevant like contact and address of the place, language and so on

The JSON file looks like this

```
actions
     0  "click"
augmented_tags  []

button_ids
     0    "0±±ui-id-1883"

context null

extended_url    "https://www.neimanmarcus.com/en-gb/p/loro-piana-andre-denim-sport-shirt-prod200810299?ecid=NMAF__ShopStyle++Collective&CS_003=5630585&utm_medium=affiliate&utm_source=NMAF__ShopStyle++Collective"

features    {}

html_filename   "ex8560step01.large.html"
placeholders    

     0      null

skip_augmentation   true

step    1
```

I need to classify which one is a good practice add basket button and those that are not.

My idea was to have the algorithm open the web page then visualize the page itself and then compared to the best practice pages that I can use a label
It will be a CNN classification or ResNet If I want to be more sophisticated
I don't think is an NLP matter.

I am wrong?
Any ideas?
If this is the case how I make the CNN focus on the position of the Add basked button.

I have been asked to do this with Neural Networks

Thanks

Comment: Remember, it's ` not ' when doing code blocks

Comment: Thank you. I had at the moment an Italian keyboard and don't have it
But my fault not to used properly

Answer (score 0):

If you have a lot of examples of good and bad buttons, you could possibly use a CNN for this.

I would use selenium to load the page, locate the element, get the dimensions of the element, take a screenshot of the page, then crop the screenshot based on the image location and dimensions.

Feed that into your classifier

[How to capture the screenshot of a specific element rather than entire page using Selenium Webdriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13832322/how-to-capture-the-screenshot-of-a-specific-element-rather-than-entire-page-usin)

However I suspect what you're looking for has as much to do with the underlying code as it does the visual representation of the button, at which point i'm not sure image classification makes a ton of sense.

Comment: My fault. I did not express correctly 
I need to say what is the "right" add basket button. 
The one that is correct. I need the CNN to focus on the add basket button
in the sense that it is in the right position or best practice position which varies a bit from web page to a web page.
I thought to  label as web pages outside the dataset that are good practice as good and then and then compare it with the one in the dataset