# Having problems with types bytes vs base64 TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Tags: python, base64, byte, typeerror

I am having problems with my types and would be really glad if you could help me.
I am downloading a captcha using

```
captcha = self.chrome_driver.driver.find_element_by_xpath(captcha_xpath).screenshot_as_png
```

which according the documentation: *saves the screenshot of the current element as a binary data.*
Then i want to send it to twocaptcha function `normal(captcha, caseSensitive=True)` which according to the documentation takes image or base64. So when i run the function i get error

> TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str
> The type of captcha is <class 'bytes'>

How to convert the captcha to base64 or image in order to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply replace your `.screeshot_as_png` with `.screenshot_as_base64()` per the list of methods [here](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html).

```
get_screenshot_as_base64()
    Gets the screenshot of the current window as a base64 encoded string
    which is useful in embedded images in HTML.
Usage:  driver.get_screenshot_as_base64()
```

The likely bigger problem you'll face is that you're searching for an element and both of these methods are to save the whole screen.  I'd suggest in addition to saving as base64 you read one of the many other [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13832322/how-to-capture-the-screenshot-of-a-specific-element-rather-than-entire-page-usin) on Stack about this subject if your intention was not to save the entire screen.