# Can you web scrape with css formatting?

Tags: python, html, css, web-scraping

I want to make a python bot that can interact with Symbolab. Here is an [example](https://www.symbolab.com/solver/step-by-step/%5Cint%5Csin%5E%7B2%7D%5Cleft(x%5Cright)dx?or=sug). I have tried using the requests library and an example of the HCTI library to render the page as an image. Whenever I do this, the page looses its formatting. I am new to web scraping but I presume this is due to the css not being rendered as I was just grabbing the html. Is there I way that I can save an image file of a site like Symbolab in a way that renders the page like a web browser (all of the equations are readable etc)?

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that the css is not rendered. When you use the `requests` library, you just get what you `get` for. If you look at **symbolab's** page, their css is found in `<link href="/public/auto/main.min.css?110025" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css">` inside the `head` of the html of the page.

If you want to use HCTI (which I assume is `https://htmlcsstoimage.com/`?), it looks like they accept an `html` parameter as well as a separate `css` parameter. So you could just have another request to `https://www.symbolab.com/public/auto/main.min.css?110025` to get the CSS and use that with HCTI.

**But this is only assuming there is no other CSS reference on their page and that this URL doesn't become invalid.** To resolve this, you could scrape the html you received for CSS references and always get the most up to date links.

An easier solution might be to just use **Selenium** to programmatically control a browser, which will do all the rendering like if you were on a regular browser. Then you can take a screenshot of the page using Selenium still. Or even a picture of a specific element. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13834607/4946011)

Hope this helps.