# How can I add buttons on a picture?

Tags: java, image, swing, jbutton

I am currently creating a GUI for a game. I am currently loading an image using JLabel onto my JPanel, I was wondering whether it would be possible to add buttons on various parts of the image e.g. (5,7) and (12,12).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wish to have `JButtons` appear over your image, a better approach would be to override the `paintComponent` of the `JPanel` and use [drawImage](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawImage%28java.awt.Image,%20int,%20int,%20java.awt.image.ImageObserver%29) to draw the image similar to [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299495/java-swing-how-to-add-an-image-to-a-jpanel) . This will allow you to add components to the container.

Absolute positioning(`null` layout) is generally frowned upon for setting component locations, however. This [DragLayout](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2011/10/23/drag-layout/) should be a better substitute taking care of component sizing.

> DragLayout was designed to replace a null layout. It will respect the location of a component. By default it will use the preferred size of the component to determines its size. Finally, it will automatically calculate the preferred size of the Container.

Comment: @Reimeus `JLayeredPane` not useful in overlapping?

Comment: @joeyrohan This could be achieved using `JLayeredPane`, however IMHO using a background image thru `paintComponent` is a simpler solution (in terms of implementation & possible scaling).