# JButton only appears after I hover over it?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jbutton, gridbaglayout

I was wondering why my button does not show up on the panel until AFTER I hover my mouse over where it would be? It also disappears again if I resize the window. The MainMenuScreen is just an image I use as my background image.

```
    //MainMenu setup
    JPanel card2 = new JPanel();
    card2.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());       
    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    gbc.insets = new Insets(2,2,2,2);
    gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
    MainMenuScreen mms = new MainMenuScreen();
    mms.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    card2.add(mms);
    card2.add(menuButton1, gbc);
```

Here is how I setup by background image.

```
public class MainMenuScreen extends JPanel{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private BufferedImage background;

    public MainMenuScreen() {
        try {
            background = ImageIO.read(new File("M&M Arcade.png"));          
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(800, 600);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if (background != null) {
            int x = (getWidth() - background.getWidth());
            int y = (getHeight() - background.getHeight());
            g.drawImage(background, x, y, this);
        }

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.setPaint(Color.white);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `JButton` doesn't show up beacuse you are using the same `GridBagConstraints` values for your `MainMenuScreen` component and your `JButton` `menuButton1`, i.e. they exist at the same location. Once the values of `gbc` are adjusted, the button will appear. Also better to consistently use the correct overloaded method of [add](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#add%28java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object%29) when adding to a container with `GridBagLayout`.

**Edit:**

There have been numerous discussions on how to implement background images on `JPanel` containers. A notable one is [Background Panel](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/12/background-panel/).

Comment: I would like the button to show up on top of the image. Is there a way I can do that? @Reimeus

Comment: Sure, there are loads of posts on how that can be done such as [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/299495/java-swing-how-to-add-an-image-to-a-jpanel). Also see update

Comment: I actually do one of those @Reimeus
See edit.
I feel like the image is being treated as a component in the gridbaglayout?

Comment: Your `menuButton1` would need to be added to your `MainMenuScreen` for the image to appear behind the button.

Comment: Instead of card2.add(menuButton1, gbc); I use mms.add(menuButton1, gbc); How then can I position my button to be where I need it? @Reimeus

Comment: That question deserves a new post. In the new post add a description of your positioning requirements and add an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) :)

Comment: posted "JButton positioning on a JPanel using GBC/GBL"