# Draw Grapics2D in JPanel from other class

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I have an array with multiple Grapics2D Objects and want to draw all of them in a Panel. Its not drawing anything. Does anyone know how to fix this?

```
for (Graphics2D g2d : models) {
     myPanel.paint(g2d);
}
```

Comment: The above code is completely wrong. Read the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for more information on painting basics and working examples. You can also check out: [Custom Painting Approaches](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/) for an example that paints all the objects in an ArrayList.

Comment: This code is very strange. Normally the framework calls your component to paint it, passing in a Graphics2D, and for a JPanel, you override paintComponent, not paint. Where are you getting these Graphics2D objects? Why are you calling paint like this?

Comment: Also, it doesn't make any sense to talk about drawing a Graphics2D in a Panel. A Graphics2D isn't something you draw, it's something you draw *with*.

Comment: Complete examples are cited [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38293273/230513).