# JPanel and BufferedImage

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, bufferedimage, java-2d

How do you display a BufferedImage in a JPanel ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Try this :](https://stackoverflow.com/a/299555/1743852)

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class ImagePanel extends JPanel{

private BufferedImage image;

public ImagePanel() {
   try {                
      image = ImageIO.read(new File("image name and path"));
   } catch (IOException ex) {
        // handle exception...
   }
}

@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null); // see javadoc for more info on the parameters            
}

}
```

and try to read this [Example to display BufferedImage as ImageIcon](http://java-buddy.blogspot.com/2012/10/example-to-display-bufferedimage-as.html)

Comment: Thank you, that has helped a lot.

Comment: You are welcome anytime :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure right now but I believe you need to do an

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("image path"));
ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon(image);
img.setVisible(true);
add(img);
```

inside the constructor.
I cant remember right now and I dont have the compiler to hand to test but thats how I add images to the panel normaly and the just call `super.repaint();` as needed.

Edit: I believe`repaint();` will do the job too.