# Slick2D How to Assign a PNG to a Variable

Tags: java, image, lwjgl, slick2d

How to you assign a png to a variable and then draw it on a specific x and y? Please no OpenGL bindings and such.

Comment: This link answers most of your question. Drawing on it should be done, I assume, by overriding the paintComponent method as in a panel, but I'm not positive: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/299495/java-swing-how-to-add-an-image-to-a-jpanel

Comment: Will this work with Slick2D though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the image in a `org.newdawn.slick.Image` with

```
Image img = new Image("/path/to/img");
```

Then draw it in the `render` function with

```
img.draw(x, y);
```

[Image.Image(String ref)](http://slick.ninjacave.com/javadoc/org/newdawn/slick/Image.html#Image%28java.lang.String%29)

[Image.draw(float x, float y)](http://slick.ninjacave.com/javadoc/org/newdawn/slick/Image.html#draw%28float,%20float%29)