# displaying image in java, no main class found

Tags: java, swing

I have the following code set to display an image on my hard drive.  however, whenever I run the code I get the following error

```
import java.awt.*;  
import java.awt.Graphics.*;  
import java.awt.event.*;  
import java.awt.image.*;  
import java.io.*;  
import javax.imageio.*;  
import javax.swing.*;  
import javax.swing.JFrame;  
  
  
public class ImagePanel extends JPanel{  
  
    public ImagePanel() {  
      setTitle("ImagePanel");  
      setSize(500,250);  
      setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);  
      setVisible(true);  
    public void (Graphics g){  
      Image image = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Public\\Pictures\\Sample Pictures\\Desert.jpg")).getImage();  
      g.drawImage(image,3,4, this);  
    }  
   
public static void main(String[] args) {  
  ImagePanel img = new ImagePanel();  
}  
}
```

and the error I get:

```
<No main classes found>
```

Comment: How do you run the code?

Comment: Will that even compile??? `public void (Graphics g)`???

Comment: The `public static void main (String[] args)` you show in the snippet is exactly correct.  So that part of the code is correct.  Either you're not running the right class, or you're not invoking the class correctly.  Q: Did you actually *COMPILE* this class???

Comment: you don't have a closing brace for "ImagePanel() "

Comment: ... or a declared method name for your painting method. And you're trying to read in a file inside of a paint method -something you should never do. Please if you have code that won't compile, do post your compilation errors. Don't make us guess.

Comment: And don't even try to run code that doesn't compile. It makes no sense. Read the error messages you get from the compiler, fix all the errors, and then only you can run the application. That's somthing you should know much before doing GUI programming with Swing which is quite complex.

Comment: Thanks for not replying to any of our comments or questions, for not clarifying your problem for us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Want to display `Image`, try something like this:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ImagePanel extends JPanel{
    private BufferedImage bi;

    public ImagePanel() {  

      try {
            bi = ImageIO.read(new File("Your Image Path"));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ImagePanel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }


        final JPanel panel = new JPanel(){
            @Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
                Graphics g2 = g.create();
                g2.drawImage(bi, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), null);
                g2.dispose();
            }

            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize(){
                return new Dimension(bi.getWidth()/2, bi.getHeight()/2);
                //return new Dimension(200, 200);
            }
        };

        add(panel);
    }  

        public static void main(String args[]){
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                ImagePanel imgPanel=new ImagePanel();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
                        null, imgPanel, "Image Panel", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
            }
        });
        }
}
```

---

**Output**

[image: Panel]

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted has syntax errors, thus cannot be successfully compiled.

For example:

```
public void (Graphics g){  
  Image image = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Public\\Pictures\\Sample Pictures\\Desert.jpg")).getImage();  
  g.drawImage(image,3,4, this);  
}
```

Is it a method? If yes, what is its method name?

I think you'd better refer to this page: [How to add an image to a JPanel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299495/how-to-add-an-image-to-a-jpanel)