# Loading an image into a background in java

Tags: java, jframe, jpanel

How do you load an image into a background in Java? I have tried many different methods and none of them work so I am asking if anyone knows how to upload a png image into a jpannel

Comment: Post the code of all those things you have tried.

Comment: This was asked before here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/299495/how-to-add-an-image-to-a-jpanel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your own JPanel. Add an object of PicPanel in your GUI's constructor.

```
class PicPanel extends JPanel{

    private BufferedImage image;
    private int w,h;
    public PicPanel(String fname){ //Pass picture's filename as a parameter.

        //reads the image
        try {
            image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/"+fname));
            w = image.getWidth();
            h = image.getHeight();

        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println("Could not read in the pic");
            //System.exit(0);
        }

    }

    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(w,h);
    }
    //this will draw the image
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(image,0,0,this);
    }
}
```

Comment: While this would certainly work, if you're doing nothing but painting the image, a `JLabel` would be simpler...just saying...

Comment: This is how my programming teacher did it...this is how I do it...and it has worked out pretty well so far :-)

Comment: Then your programming teacher needs some new lessons ;) - in two lines I can do what you entire class has done

Comment: But you just said: "The problem with this is the JLabel won't resize the image when the frame is resized" so why are you recommending that ?

Comment: Yeah MadProgrammer! Explain yourself! D:<

Comment: @GabrielBB and @Solace Neither will either of the examples that both of you have suggested. With out context to what the OP wants, I suggested both the use of a `JLabel` and custom painting approach, using a number of different scaling approaches, check the 2 links in answer

Answer (score 0):

There are any number of ways this might be achieved.

### You Could...

Create a `JLabel`, apply the image to it's `icon` property and set this as the frames content pane.  You would then need to set the layout manager appropriately, as `JLabel` doesn't have a default layout manager

```
JFrame frame = ...;
JLabel background = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(...)));
frame.setContentPane(background);
frame.setLayout(...);
frame.add(...);
```

The problem with this is the `JLabel` won't resize the image when the frame is resized

### You Could...

Create a custom component, extending from something like `JPanel` and override it's `paintComponent` method, painting the background as you see fit.

This provides you with the ability to decide how best the image should be scaled when it's available space changes.  While there are a number of ways this might be achived, you should read through [The Perils of Image.getScaledInstance()](https://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/04/03/perils-of-image-getscaledinstance.html) to understand the pros and cons of them.

This raises a bunch of new questions, to you want to scale them and preserve the aspect ratio? If so, do you want to fit the image to available area or fill it (so it will always cover the available space)?

Take a look at [Java: maintaining aspect ratio of JPanel background image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11959758/java-maintaining-aspect-ratio-of-jpanel-background-image/11959928#11959928) for more details.

**Other considerations**

Images are generally best loaded through the `ImageIO` API, as it's capable of loading a wide range of images, but will also throw an `IOException` when something goes wrong.

See [Reading/Loading an Image](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html) for more details.

The location of the image is also important.  If the image is external to the application (somewhere on the file system), you can use `ImageIO.read(new File("/path/to/image"))`.  However, if the the image is embedded within your application (stored within the Jar for example), you will need to use something more like `ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/path/to/image"))` instead...