# Error adding image to JPanel because variable is not initialise

Tags: java, image, swing, embedded-resource, bufferedimage

I am trying to [add an image to a JPanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299495/how-to-add-an-image-to-a-jpanel?rq=1)

```
package testing;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.security.*;
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;
import java.lang.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;


public class Testing extends JPanel 
{        
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        BufferedImage myPicture;           
        try
        {    
             myPicture = ImageIO.read(new File("./src/testing/cal.png"));
        }
        catch (IOException ex) {
            // handle exception...
        }
        JLabel picLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(myPicture));//error is here            
        Testing t = new Testing();
        t.add(picLabel);    
    }
}
```

I get the following error

```
 variable myPicture might not have been initialize
```

I thought i already initialise myPicture with the following line

```
 myPicture = ImageIO.read(new File("./src/testing/cal.png"));
```

**It seems I am wrong about it , how do i resolve this error so that I can add a image to a JPanel**

Comment: By the time of deployment, those resources will likely become an [tag:embedded-resource].  That being the case, the resource must be accessed by `URL` instead of `File`.  See the [info page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for the tag, for a way to form an `URL`.

Answer (score 1):

```
BufferedImage myPicture = null;
```

Answer (score 1):

You initialize it inside the try block, you have to give it some arbitrary value outside the try block, like null, so the compiler knows the value is always initialized, even if the try fails.