# load image to JPanel not working

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

For two days I was trying to load an image into `JPanel` from a file. I couldn't!

I used `JLabel` and `Icon` and it's loaded okay, but I need to load the image to a `JPanel` directly, is that impossible?

Because almost I saw many and many related problems like this and many people recommended the person who asks the question to load the image into a label!

this is the code :

```
public class ReadingImage extends JPanel  {
JPanel panel;
JFrame frame; 
JPanel secPanel;
private BufferedImage img;


public ReadingImage(String path){
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setLocation(300, 300);
    frame.setSize(300, 500);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    secPanel  = new JPanel();
    secPanel.setVisible(true);
    //secPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    secPanel.repaint();

    frame.getContentPane().add(secPanel);

    try{
        FileImageInputStream fi = new FileImageInputStream(new File(path));
        //System.out.println(path);
        img = ImageIO.read(fi);
        this.repaint();
    }
    catch (IOException io ){ io.printStackTrace();}
}

@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponents(g);
    if (img!=null){
        g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, this);
        repaint();
    }
}
}
```

It's not throwing any exception, but it's not displaying the image in the `JPanel`!

I adjusted the code many and many times..

any help in this :)

thanks,

Comment: Did you try the solution mentioned here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/299495/how-to-add-an-image-to-a-jpanel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Classic confusion caused by extending `JPanel` and using another JPanel. Replace `frame.getContentPane().add(secPanel)` with `frame.add(this , BORDERLAYOUT.CENTER)` and everything should work fine.

Comment: thanks a lot :)
I didn't expect that this is the sly mistake :)

could I ask if we can add the picture in a fixed size, so through my program I'm deciding which size is better rather than the photo size ?

thanks :)

Comment: sure, `Graphics` also provides other methods to paint images. Use: `g.drawImage(img , x , y , width , height , null)` to paint the image

Comment: @Paul You should use `g.drawImage(img, x, y, this)` otherwise the component may not know when the image state changes

Answer (score 2):

You are calling `super.paintComponents(g);` in `paintComponent`, not the `s` at the end, this is going to cause a `StackOverflowException` eventually, but don't actually ever add the `ReadingImage` `JPanel` to anything, so it's never actually painted

This means that there doesn't seem to be any point any point to the `secPane`

You should also avoid creating frames from within other components, especially from within the constructor, it provides a very limit use case for the component

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.imageio.stream.FileImageInputStream;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class ReadingImage extends JPanel {

    private BufferedImage img;

    public ReadingImage(String path) {
        try {
            FileImageInputStream fi = new FileImageInputStream(new File(path));
            img = ImageIO.read(fi);
            this.repaint();
        } catch (IOException io) {
            io.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if (img != null) {
            g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, this);
            repaint();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new ReadingImage("Your image"));
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLocation(300, 300);
                frame.setSize(300, 500);
                frame.setVisible(true);

            }
        });
    }

}
```

I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to achieve, but I would also encourage you to override the `ReadingImage`'s `getPreferredSize` method and return the size of the image, this makes it easier to layout

Answer (score 0):

first load the image in Image Icon, lets say the object as 'pic'.

**panel1.add(new JLabel(pic));**

add and set panel1 to visible.

Comment: Swing components are visible by default (with the exception of `Window` based classes and `JInternalFrame`)