# Why won't my existing image draw to the screen?

Tags: java, graphics, bufferedimage

Basically here's the deal, I'm trying to load an image from a source file within the Project, but whenever I run the code nothing happens.

Can anyone shed some light on where I am going wrong, and maybe possibly how to get it to draw correctly?

Here's the code:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;


public class EnterTile extends Tile {

public EnterTile() {
    setTile();
}

public void setTile() {

    try {
        BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File("res\\BrokenFenceSwamp.gif"));
        Graphics g = img.getGraphics();
        g.drawImage(img, 1000, 1000, 8, 8, null);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error " + e);
    }
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    EnterTile enterTile = new EnterTile();


}



}
```

Thanks for taking the time to read this.

Comment: You are not drawing on any UI component - [BufferedImage.getGraphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Image.html#getGraphics())returns a graphics context to draw to an off-screen image.

Comment: So I could essentially create a new JPanel and draw the image onto that?

Comment: Essentially, yes. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/299495/how-to-add-an-image-to-a-jpanel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting the Graphics of an image is a facility to be able to draw on images:

```
    BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File("res\\BrokenFenceSwamp.gif"));

    Graphics g = img.getGraphics();
    g.drawString(img, 100, 100, "Hello World!");
    g.dispose();

    ImageIO.write(new File("res/TitledBFS.gif"));
```

It does not draw on the screen.
`Graphics` can be memory (here), screen or printer.

To draw on the screen, one would make a full-screen window without title and borders, an on its background draw the image.

That would require becoming acquainted with swing or the newer JavaFX.

Answer (score 1):

To load the image correctly you need to:

1. Have the **res** folder (where the image is stored) marked as a resource folder.
2. When you call the **read()** method of ImageIO, you need to pass a URL. To do that you need to use ***{className}*.class.getResource(*{path}*)** *(In your case* `ImageIO.read(EnterTile.class.getResource("/BrokenFenceSwamp.gif"));`)

To draw the image you need to specify where. *E.g. canvas if you are using awt library.* You can try something like this:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Image Test");
        frame.setSize(400, 800);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setFocusable(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setResizable(false);

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
        canvas.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 800));
        canvas.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(400, 800));
        canvas.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(400, 800));

        frame.add(canvas);
        frame.pack();

        canvas.createBufferStrategy(2);    
        BufferStrategy bs = canvas.getBufferStrategy();

        Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
        g.clearRect(0, 0, 400, 800);

        String path = "/BrokenFenceSwamp.gif";
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(Main.class.getResource(path));

        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);

        bs.show();
        g.dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: Whilst using your code, a null pointer exception occurred during run-time at  `Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics()`?

Comment: I edited the code so you need to first call `canvas.createBufferStrategy(2);` and after that `BufferStrategy bs = canvas.getBufferStrategy();`. The reason why I posted the code with the `if (bs == null)` condition is that I copied this code from a game of mine where the bufferStrategy is constantly being checked in a loop. But for drawing only once, first create the strategy by calling it on the canvas and afterwards `getBufferStrategy()` to instantiate the BufferStrategy variable. Tell me if it works :)