# adding multiple images in java gui

Tags: java, image, user-interface, netbeans

I'm trying to add multiple `images` to `JLabel`. The problem is that it is impossible to add more than one image, and I don't know how many `images` I will need in advance.
How can I overcome the problem? mabye not `JLabel`..

Thanks

Comment: Provide more details, and the code you have.

Answer (score 1):

1) Show us what you've done so far :)

2) Short answer is that you can't. `JLabels` and `JButtons` can only have one image associated. So you can either have multiple dynamically created `JLabels` or `JPanels`.

3) I don't understand why you want the image in a `JLabel`.

**SOLUTION**

Create a `JPanel` called `container` and give it a `grid layout`. Dynamically create more `JPanels (pnl1, pnl2, etc)` and add them to container. Each image should be added to `pnl1, pnl2, etc`.

Create a class [image panel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299495/how-to-add-an-image-to-a-jpanel) that extends jpanel as your container for each image.

If you don't know during `compile time`, I assume you know during `runtime`? Which means you just keep creating new panels until you run out of images.

In your `Image Panel` class you'll also want to assign an `id` for each `image panel` in the event that you want to be able to utilize or change the content/image later. So you'll find panels by `id` and not by variable name because those will all be dynamic and you won't have them.

Comment: It doesn't have to be Jlabel, if you have a better idea.
And how can I add dynamically Jlabels?
Thank you very much