# How to add image in Java Swing?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jlabel

Help! How can I add image on my `JFrame`? This is my code

```
public class JavaApplication79 extends JFrame{

 ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("Downloads/splash.jpg");
 JLabel label = new JLabel(icon);

public JavaApplication79(){
    add(label);

    setLayout(null);
    setSize(900,500);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

public static void main(String args[]){
JavaApplication79 show = new JavaApplication79();
show.setVisible(true);
}
 }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add an image to a JPanel?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/299495/how-to-add-an-image-to-a-jpanel)

Comment: *`setLayout(null);`* Uh-huh. Add a `LineBorder` to the `JLabel`

Comment: 1) A single blank line of white space in source code is all that is *ever* needed.  Blank lines after `{` or before `}` are also typically redundant. 2) Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow!

Answer (score 1):

The problems start with the `null` layout. Because there is no layout to set the component size to it's preferred size, or any other size, the panel takes its default **size of 0 x 0 pixels.**

---

- For 'top left' of frame I'd recommend `FlowLayout`.
- For 'center' of frame - `GridBagLayout` is easy.
- For 'centered & stretched' to fill the frame, `GridLayout`.

Learn about layouts in the [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) lesson of the tutorial.

But an extra tip about combining layouts for different effects in different parts of the GUI.  Use layout managers, or ***[combinations of them](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556)*** along with layout ***padding and borders*** for [white space](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556).