# Add image icons to buttons/labels Swing

Tags: java, swing, maven, icons, embedded-resource

I know that this question has already been posted, but I've tried everything I found and nothing worked.

I have a Maven project, and I want to use images on buttons. I put the images in the `src/main/res folder`. After a Maven clean/ Maven install, all my images are found in the `target/classes` folder. I want the images to be inside the `.jar` file, so that I don't need to create a separate folder when using it.

This is the code I try to use to load the image for a new icon on my button:

```
JButton button = new JButton();
      try {
        Image img = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("cross_icon.jpg"));
        button.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img));
      } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
      }
       subsPanel.add(button);
```

but I get a `input == null`. I tried using `main/res/cross_icon.jpg` or `res/cross_icon.jpg`, but nothing worked.

Comment: Is the word "folder" part of the path? More examples are cited [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must put a `/` at the beginning of the resource path if it is an absolute path when loading a resource via `Class.getResource`.

```
Image img = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/cross_icon.jpg"));
```

See the javadoc of [`Class.getResource`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource-java.lang.String-)

> Before delegation, an absolute resource name is constructed from the given resource name using this algorithm:
>
> - If the name begins with a '/' ('\u002f'), then the absolute name of the >resource is the portion of the name following the '/'.
> - Otherwise, the absolute name is of the following form:
>
>   ```
>   modified_package_name/name
>   ```
>
>   Where the modified_package_name is the package name of this object with '/' >substituted for '.' ('\u002e').

**PS**

If you use `ClassLoader.getResource` the resource name is always interpreted as an absolute path. E.g.

```
Image img = ImageIO.read(getClass()
                         .getClassLoader()
                         .getResource("cross_icon.jpg"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    URL url = getClass().getResource(".");
    System.out.println(url);
    url = getClass().getResource("cross_icon.jpg");
    System.out.println(url);
    Image img = ImageIO.read(url);
    System.out.println(img);
    button.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img));
```

getResource () will create url, by appending the given path with the base path(the path of your .class)

Comment: `URL url = getClass().getResource(".");` this location will change in ways that often mean the paths do not point where the programmer would expect them to. 
The correct approach is outlined and explained in the answer of @RenéLink.