# Add an image to a canvas

Tags: java, swing, graphics, awt

I know there are stack overflow questions on here about this but I am not extending canvas in my class. Is there any other way to just draw an image on the background?

```java
//setting up a JFrame with other stuff
Canvas c = new Canvas();
Image img;
try {
    img = ImageIO.read(new URL("https://bitterli.us/namelogo.png").openStream());
    img = img.getScaledInstance(700, 145, 0);
} catch (IOException e2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e2.printStackTrace();
}
c.setBackground(Color.black);
JPanel p = new JPanel();
c.setBounds(100, 500, 1050, 500);
p.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
p.add(c, BorderLayout.CENTER);
p.setBounds(100, 50, 1050, 600);
frame.add(p, BorderLayout.NORTH);
```

Comment: You need to extend Canvas (as per the other questions) and draw within its paint method. Either that or add a JLabel and display the image as an ImageIcon within the label. Why are you using the AWT GUI library to begin with since this is over 20 years out of date?

Comment: Also, setBounds is not your friend

Answer (score 0):

Don't used canvas, just use a `JPanel` and override `paintComponent()`.

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
  super.paintComponent(g);
  g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
}
```

Comment: probably best answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299495/how-to-add-an-image-to-a-jpanel